# QR Factorization - Derivation of the R matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble understanding why the $R$ matrix in a $QR$ factorization is constructed the way is, based on the definitions given in my introductory linear algebra textbook.

Suppose we have a matrix *m* x *n* matrix $A$ and a matrix $Q$ whose columns form an orthonormal set $ W \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and the *n* x *n* upper triangular matrix $R$ such that $$A = QR$$

The textbook states that the $R$ matrix will be constructed as followed $$R=\begin{bmatrix} r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\ 0 & r_{12} & r_{13} \\ 0 & 0 & r_{33}\end{bmatrix} \text{, where } r_{ij} = \mathbf{a_j \bullet w_i} \text{ for all } i,j$$

Why does $ r_{ij} = \mathbf{a_j \bullet w_i} \text{ for all } i,j$?